# Wien bridge oscillator frequency

Tags: operational-amplifier, oscillator, oscillation, wien-bridge

Question from *Microelectronic Circuits* by Sedra and Smith, **Section 17.2: Op Amp–RC Oscillator Circuits**:

> **17.10** For the Wien-bridge oscillator of Fig. 17.4, let
> the closed-loop amplifier (formed by the op amp and the resistors R1 and R2) exhibit a phase shift of −0.1 rad in the neighborhood of w1=1/CR. Find the frequency at which oscillations can occur in this case in terms of CR. (Hint:
> Use Eq. 17.11.)

I had a doubt in this question.

I considered the phase shift to be provided only by the amplifier as the feedback loop provides zero phase shift for w1=1/CR and thus for oscillation feedback circuit should provide +0.1 rad so that A*beta =1.

For that I'm getting w(oscillation) to be less than w1,  which is wrong according to the solution.

It should be 1.15w1.

This problem is from Sedra Smith 6th edition. I don't know where I made a mistake.

Please help.

[image: schematic]

Comment: I believe what it is telling you that the op-amp doesn't quite produce 0 degrees phase shift from the positive input but 5.73 degrees. Then you have to calculate at what frequency the oscillation occurs given that the Wien bridge impedances have to overcompensate for this phase error.

Comment: NEELANSHU, I think I would agree with you. When the opamp causes a parasitic negative phase shift the WIEN network must compensate this "error" with a corresponding positive phase shift - resulting in an oscillation frequency which is BELOW the nominal case. By the way - in Sedra-Smith 7th. edition I cannot find any remark about such a influence of a real opamp.

Comment: @Andyaka Do you mean opamp produces -5.73degree phase shift because question mentions the closed loop to be showing -0.1 rad in neighbourhood of w1=1/CR and at w=w1 phase shift from wein bridge goes to be zero; implying the -3 degree phase shift to be from opamp. To which at oscillation frequency, wein bridge has to compensate by providing +3 degree phase shift to make overall phase shift zero. Btw in 7th edition Sedra smith its ques 12 btw and edition 6 is 10.

Comment: @LvW Yeah I guess there is no remark . I have taken  assumption that opamp o/p is frequency independent and thus the phase shift introduced by it (if any )is constant for all frequency . I have solved ques 16 of sedra smith edition 7 with similar approach and got correct answer  and i still cant figure out where i went wrong with this one...

"Redesign the circuit of Fig. 17.6 for operation at
10 kHz using the same values of resistance. If at 10 kHz the
op amp provides an excess phase shift (lag) of 5.7°, what
will be the frequency of oscillation?"

Comment: I don’t understand the -3 you mention.

Comment: oh that is -3 degree(-0.1 radians) .Each edition has different value of this parameter, like I think in yours its -5.73 degree.

Comment: NEELANSHU, one thing is undoubtly clear: For real opamps (with lagging phase characteristics) the oscillation frequency is ALWAYS smaller than the ideal one. The reason is as follows: The frequency-dependent feedback path must have a phase function with a negative slope around the oscillation frequency - otherwise the oscillation condition is not fulfilled (This extension to the well known Barkhausen criterion is a relatively new finding). This means:  Only a frequency reduction allows a small positive phase correction.